# How to set my map marker at the center of div when page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I actually using `geocode`.

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST){

$data_arr = geocode($_REQUEST['search_city']);

if($data_arr){

$latitude = $data_arr[0];
$longitude = $data_arr[1];
$formatted_address = $data_arr[2];

?>

<div id="map_canvas" style="/*width:100%;*/ height:300px;">
    Loading map...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>,<?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>,<?php echo $longitude; ?>
        ),
        title: '<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>
        });
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "
    <?php echo $formatted_address; ?>
        "
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>

<?php

}else{
echo "No map found.";
}
}

function geocode($address) {

    $address = urlencode($address);

    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}";
    $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);
    $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);
    if ($resp['status'] == 'OK') {

        $lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        $formatted_address = $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'];

        if ($lati && $longi && $formatted_address) {

            $data_arr = array();

            array_push($data_arr, $lati, $longi, $formatted_address);
            return $data_arr;

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Here,the map marker is viewed at the top left corner of the map like this,

[image]

And I wrote `map.panTo(marker.getPosition());` inside a `google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {});` function.

So,if the marker get clicked I get back to the center of the map.

But I need to show the marker at center once the page loads.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding two extra parameters in **myoptions** variable and change position as you want instead of **TOP_CENTER** in **mapTypeControlOptions**.

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 20,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
    }
};
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-positioning

Comment: Really nice.. :) It works for me great.. Thank you so much.. :)